# Meteor reactive var not rendered consistently

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, reactive

I've read through all of the reactive var questions here plus
[this meteorchef article](https://blog.meteor.com/the-meteor-chef-reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables-971584515a27) and am still having trouble with my app.

foo.js:

```
    Template.pwdStrength.onCreated(function() {
      this.reason = new ReactiveVar('Empty password');
    });

  Template.pwdStrength.helpers({
    reason: function() {
      return Template.instance().reason.get();
    },
  });

  Template.pwdStrength.events({
    'input #at-field-password': function(event, template) {
      const contents = event.currentTarget.value;
      // call strength computation here...
      if (contents.length < 8) {
        Template.instance().reason.set('Password is too short');
      } else {
        Template.instance().reason.set("We don't like that password");
      }
    }
  });
```

foo.html:

```
<template name='pwdStrength1'>
{{> atTextInput}}
  <span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title="{{reason}}">
    <ul id="strength" check-strength="pw" style="{display: inline;}">
      <li class="point" style="{{style 1}}"></li>
      <li class="point" style="{{style 2}}"></li>
      <li class="point" style="{{style 3}}"></li>
      <li class="point" style="{{style 4}}"></li>
      <li class="point" style="{{style 5}}"></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</template>
```

The goal is to display a tooltip over the password strength meter with the reason that was set by the input event. The tooltip comes up as "Empty password" even after entering text into the password field. But if I add a line with just `{{reason}}` at the top of the template, the reason is shown on the page, PLUS the tooltip now works as expected and shows the updating reason. If I use CSS to hide the `{{reason}}` then the tooltip stops working. It appears that the template helper must be rendered before rendering the one in the  tag. What am I doing wrong?

Latest Meteor, twbs:bootstrap, accounts:templates.

---

**EDIT**

Gave up on this because the UI wasn't intuitive and the tooltips just got in the way. Never actually found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use template.reason.set('Password is too short');
Instead of Template.instance().reason.set('Password is too short');

Comment: Nope, then neither the tooltip or the naked {{reason}} gets updated.

Comment: Maybe it dosen't reach the if block try to add console.log(contents.length)